# Tracking Hashtags & Querystrings in GA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, query-string, tracking, qr-code

I have a few stickers which contain my website's URL QR Code (like this : http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=5&d=http%3A%2F%2Fissocial.net%23qr) . I will stick it to streets. As you can see if someone read this QR code, he will forward to http://issocial.net/#qr page.

Now i want to track people who reach my site via this QR Code Stickers. Sadly, Google Analytics isn't tracking hashtags.

Maybe i can do it with querystring (like : http://issocial.net/?qr=true) . But GA isn't tracking just one querystring.

So, have you any idea about this?

Comment: What about a QR Code of a link with campaign parameters ?
http://qrcode.kaywa.com/img.php?s=5&d=http%3A%2F%2Fissocial.net%2F%3Futm_source%3Dsticker%26utm_medium%3Dqrcode%26utm_campaign%3Dbrand would point to http://issocial.net/?utm_source=sticker&utm_medium=qrcode&utm_campaign=brand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of _setAllowAnchor and _setCampMediumKey to force Google Analytics to (a) use your hash tag as a query string and (b) use your 'qr' in place of the normal utm _medium (or any other of the campaign variables).

More here : http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiCampaignTracking.html

Answer (score 12):

Google Analytics's default implementation ignores the anchor, ie, everything after #, so you need to pass through the value manually. `_trackPageview` can accept a 2nd parameter that allows you to pass pageview values manually.

By default, GA's pageview is just `location.pathname+location.search`. So, all you need to do is pass through that with `location.hash`.

```
_gaq.push(["_trackPageview",location.pathname + location.search + location.hash]);
```

**Universal Analytics**

With the newer UA API, the command should be:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', { 'page': location.pathname + location.search + location.hash});
```

Comment: You're mostly right, while I'm not sure it solves the initial need.
I just don't understand why you suggests to replace # by / ? GA would cope with having a value containing '#'

Comment: @open seo Ha, good point. Didn't even occur to me that GA would be fine handling the # as long as it was explicitly passed. Fixed.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me.  I much prefer myurl.com/#seo-friendly-tag than that mess of campaign parameters google analytics requires.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

In the new analytics.js it should be

`ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {'allowAnchor': true});`

Comment: According to [the reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#allowAnchor), this defaults to true and is only for campaign parameters

Answer (score 0):

No web server can track hash tags. They aren't sent to the server; they're only used by the client.

You could always just encode http://.../qr and have your server redirect to your home page. Or just have it serve up the same content as the home page in response. Or go through a shortener.

Comment: It may work client-side, but that's not relevant here. If you scan a code with a generic scanner, it will ask the browser to launch a page and the browser will not send the hash tag. The target page has no access to the hash tag. (Launching a url from your own page is completely different story.)

Comment: Yes, the browser doesn't send the anchor fragment to the server, but that target page can access it client-side.  It's definitely relevant here.  QR codes can contain whatever URL you want, including the anchor fragment.

Comment: Duh. Obviously (now) the target page could trigger something. Not my finest hour. Thanks for the correction.